# How to calculate the Electric field near a 2-D charged square sheet of conducting material with finite area?

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law, conductors

The case for infinite sheets are simple enough, and also for a disk of finite size, which can be derived as in the picture.[image: Disk Calculation]

title edited to specify sheet is finite.

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.tdgutierrez.com/2014/11/16/field-near-a-conductor/) link Adenine. It has a really nice explanation.

Comment: @PrasadMani it seems that link also explains equations involving sheets of infinite area. in the case of finite ones, shouldn't the electric vary with the distance?

Comment: What do you mean by "_near_ a 2D square sheet"?

Comment: Of course it will. Infinite sheet is just an approximation. Was your question about finite conducting sheet?

Comment: @Spirine near in the sense at point P which is at a distance d away from the sheet. I want to know E at P.

Comment: @PrasadMani Yes, sorry the original title wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Okay, then look at [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/139393/electric-field-of-a-finite-conducting-plate)

Comment: @PrasadMani this problem seems similar enough, if we assume that point P at which I want to know the electric field is vertically above the midpoint of the horizontal sheet, I would argue that we have enough symmetry to the problem to use Gauss' law?

Comment: Not entirely satisfactory probably and i am posting links because i dont know the answer myself and am searching for it but [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24248/why-we-cannot-use-gausss-law-to-find-the-electric-field-of-a-finite-length-char) is where you should go next if you havent already seen it